# How to add a new Line after every dot in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, newline

Based on a Google Doc Document I am creating a Google Apps Script which inserts available texts in the tables of the Google Doc Document into a Google Sheet. As sometimes the texts are very long, the inserted text in the Google Sheet does not look well. Also used `sheet.autoResizeColumns(3,sheet.getLastColumn())` but because of the length of the text it does not look well.

So I want to add a new Line into the String Text after every dot. I tried `testText = testText.replace('.','\n')` but this just replaces the first dot with  a new Line and also removes the dot. What I want is to have a new Line after the dot in the whole string, so not removing the dot. Example for this:

```
var testText = 'This approach is very good. Thank you very much for your Attention. We will send you messages.'
```

Wanted text:

```
var wantedText = 'This approach is very good.
                  Thank you very much for your Attention.
                  We will send you messages.'
```

How to do this in Google Apps Script?

Comment: All you need is just `testText = testText.replace(/\. /g,'.\n')`. `g` means change all. It can be read as: change `dot + space` with `dot + Enter` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals : use backtick (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes

```
function literals(){
  var wantedText = `This approach is very good.
Thank you very much for your Attention.
We will send you messages.`
  Logger.log(wantedText)
}
```

If the text comes from a cell, use :

```
function breakLine(){
  var testText = 'This approach is very good. Thank you very much for your Attention. We will send you messages.'
  var wantedText = testText.replace(/(\.)/gm,"\.\n");
  Logger.log(wantedText)
}
```

If necessary, add a space after the dot

```
var wantedText = testText.replace(/(\. )/gm,"\.\n");
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. But this does not provide a sufficient solution as I want to automate this procedure. I take text from a google doc and add it into a google sheet. The texts in the google doc are changing every time and there is very much text. I have to do it automated

Comment: I take the text by tables[4].getCell(0,0).getText();       This string I have to transform so that after every dot a new line is inserted

Comment: I have updated my answer and add a second function.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! The updated version helped a lot